# React cant get access to my url parameter(?) through Match

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My render function only contains my router:

```
return (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' render={LandingPageComponent} />
            <Route exact path='/signup' render={SignUpPageComponent}/>
            <Route exact path='/login' render={LogInPageComponent} />
            <Route path='/profile/:username' render={ProfilePageComponent}/>

            <Route render={ LandingPageComponent }/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
)
```

I am currently working on user profiles and for some reason, I cant get access to the `:username` from the profile route: `/profile/:username`.

I saw that the correct method to get the variable would be: `this.props.match.params.username` but I get an error: `Cannot read property 'params' of undefined` when I console.log it from within my `ProfilePageComponent`

I can easily get the username by splicing it out of the URL manually but I don't think I should do it that way.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Been stuck on it for this whole day.

**EDIT**

So I believe I know why this is happening now maybe thanks to JoeCo's answer.

As you can see from the code example above, I am rendering a variable.

The variables look something like this:

```
const LandingPageComponent = () => {
  return (
    <LandingPage 
      user: this.state.user
      ...etc
    />
  )
}

...
<Route exact path='/' render={ LandingPageComponent } />
```

I do it this way to make my render function a lot neater.

Im guessing maybe since I wasn't directly rendering a component, the route props wasn't being passed in so I needed to manually pass it into the component.

I could be totally wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to access match from RouteProps, you need to provide it to your component by passing it through.

```
return (
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' render={LandingPageComponent} />
        <Route exact path='/signup' render={SignUpPageComponent}/>
        <Route exact path='/login' render={LogInPageComponent} />
        <Route path='/profile/:username' render={(routeProps) => <ProfilePageComponent {...routeProps} />}/>

        <Route render={ LandingPageComponent }/>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

)

Comment: Hmm... never heard of routeProps before. Lemme look into that

Comment: Thanks man! This finally gave me what I was looking for. I didn't see any documentation or examples of this. Helped me out a lot.

Comment: I'm trying to find some good documentation for you, but only finding articles so far.  They aren't super informative.